# Fetch a Model's associations in Laravel to simplify creation/update

Tags: php, laravel, orm, synchronization

I have a Movie model with the following associations (belongsToMany):
Actor
Country
Genre
...

When a form is posted, I have this data (skipping a lot of details here):
'actors' => array(
    'Cary Grant',
    'Grace Kelly',
    ...
),
'genres' => array(
    'Drama',
    ...
),
...

I'd like my update()/store() controller function to easily associate these Models.

An actor with the name 'Cary Grant' may or may not exist and may or may not be already associated with the movie I'm editing. Also I could remove him from this movie, so I'd need to remove the association. Same with Genre and everything else.

So I thought I'd do a BaseModel and do all of this only once in there, like this:
1. get the Movie Model's defined associations.
2. check if POST data contains those associations.
3. for each of them, check if they exist (if not create them) and return an array of ids. the column I'm checking is 'name', but it could be configurable.
4. sync() those ids.

For now, I don't need to add more stuff to the related model from the movie form (ex. an actor's birthdate).

I'm stuck at n.1 ($movie->getRelations() only works for existing movies) and in general I'm not sure if this is the right approach. Hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've met the same problem and this is what I do in my project:

1. Instead of retrieving all defined relations of the models, I white-listing  relations that can be updated by adding a static member

   `Movie::$editableRelations = ['actors', 'genres', 'countries'];`
2. Loop through the post data, and match with the `$editableRelations` arrays. If the data of a relation exists, following below steps, otherwise we simply do not touch this relation.

Step 3 and step 4 are the same as yours.

Comment: Got it, so I was on the right path and I need to hard-code my relations in a static property.  How do you loop through post data without a model name to find existing relationships and create new associated entities? I can't simply remove the final 's' and change the case of the first letter, it wouldn't work with country (countries->countrie)

Comment: Can you post a sample data of your POST data?

Comment: The sample is in my original post, an array of arrays of names

Answer (score 1):

use direct relations: $model->actors

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

All sync() stuff will be done by ORM, so the most complex thing you should do is n.3. You must create diff between $model->actors and $_POST['actors'] and understand what actors you need to insert (create new actors).

Comment: Yeah, my main issue was about getting model's relationships dynamically without writing them one by one